# Java Reader for DIF [Data Interchange Format]

Tags: java

Im looking for a Java lib that can read *.dif files saved from Excel http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Interchange_Format

Is there something that could help me, or do I need to write my own implementation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out: http://sourceforge.net/projects/javadif/

To read, you use `com.csam.dif.DIFReader.read(InputStream inStream)` method which creates a new `DIFSheet` object.